# Custom Exceptions for module for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, exception

There are a few good-answered questions like this for Magento 1, but I haven't found anything for Magento 2.

What should be the way for adding in custom module custom Exception class. Can I add some constant message renedered when custom exception is catched? I have foun 'heart' of exceptions in `magento/framework/Exception`, but I am not sure if this is place which I should extend from, because there can be found some exception classes in `symfony` vendor.

Are there any good practices for Magento 2 for custom Exceptions or do you think it is not worth adding our own exceptions and we should just customize message displayed or logged?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't guarantee that it's the best solution but when reading the source code of Magento 2 core files most modules do it this way:

- Create a new folder called `Exception` in your module's directory.
- Add a new PHP class (e.g. `CustomResponseException`) to this folder
- The class `CustomResponseException` should extend the LocalizedException class. This class extends PHP's core Exception class

  This is how the file should look like:

  ```
  <?php

  namespace XYZCompany\CustomResponse\Exception;


  class CustomResponseException extends 
  \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
  {
  }
  ```
- To throw this custom exception use the following statement within your catch block:

  ```
  throw new CustomResponseException('custommessage', $e);
  ```

Comment: So far I am using the same approach!

Comment: Good to hear, I'm pretty confident that this is the solution how it should be done.