# Which method is suitable for showing errors in custom module admin grid magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I need to show syntax errors and unexpected exceptions in my custom module admin grid. Which method is suitable for this in Magento 2.

**EDIT**

Instead of save into exception.log file, I need to save to db, and show in admin grid.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm developing with Magento 2 I usually edit app/bootstrap.php and enable the line: 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link with an answer.

[Custom Exceptions for module for Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128308/custom-exceptions-for-module-for-magento-2)

I hope it helps!

Comment: I am looking for something like error handler overriding